# console.log and error is not printing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script that encrypts a file, but I want to print a console.log(); after it is encrypted right. I tried the following but it didnt work:

```
var figlet = require('figlet');
var encryptor = require('file-encryptor');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var node_cryptojs = require('node-cryptojs-aes');

figlet('ZaCrypt', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong...');
        console.dir(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(data)
});

var message = "Zaseth is my bff";
var key = encrypted_json_str;
var options = {
    algorithm: 'blowfish'
};

// Encrypt message
var r_pass = crypto.randomBytes(128);
var r_pass_base64 = r_pass.toString("base64");
var CryptoJS = node_cryptojs.CryptoJS;
var JsonFormatter = node_cryptojs.JsonFormatter;

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, r_pass_base64,
{
    format: JsonFormatter
});
var encrypted_json_str = encrypted.toString();
// Encyption complete

// Encrypt file.
encryptor.encryptFile('file.txt', 'encrypted.zaseth', message, key, options, function (err){
    if (err) {
        console.log("There was an error...");
        throw err;
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("File encrypted!");
    }
    // Encryption complete.
});
```

Why is this not working? The part of the encryption where I want to print something is at the bottom.

I just tried the following but that didn't work:

```
// Encrypt file.
encryptor.encryptFile('file.txt', 'encrypted.zaseth', message, key, options, function (err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
        console.log("File encrypted!");
    // Encryption complete.
});
```

Comment: Take it out of the `else`. You're returning after throwing an error (??) so it's redundant.

Comment: @JayGould I edited my question based on your answer.

Comment: Is the `console.log` on the figlet callback function working?

Comment: Removing the code of figlet did not fix my issue @akinjide

Comment: Then you aren't getting that far. Is your output file `encrypted.zaseth` actually there? Delete it off your disk and rerun the node script.

Comment: I already remove it in each test @JayGould

Comment: I meant regenerate the file so you can see that it's definitely coming out. If you're using an IDE that supports breakpoints I recommend stepping through your code to see if you're even entering your callback.

Comment: Also dont return a `console.log`, they should be separate lines :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue 1:

You have the expression

```
var key = encrypted_json_str
```

**before**

```
encrypted_json_str = encrypted.toString()
```

That means `key` is assigned `undefined` (since `encrypted_json_str` is still `undefined` at that moment) which will cause the `encryptFile()` method to throw an error

### Issue 2:

As @canon has already explained, you have an extra parameter, `message`, in your call to `encryptFile()`. This causes it to use your `message` parameter as its `key` argument, your `key` as `options` and your `options` as `callback`. Since your `options` isn't actually a function, when `encryptFile()` tries to invoke it (believing it to be `callback`), it throws an error saying `callback is not a function`

### Solution:

In your call to the `encryptFile()` method, remove the `message` parameter and replace the `key` parameter with `encrypted_json_str`

Comment: Yeah, the implementation of `encryptor.encryptFile()` is pretty brittle and won't properly invoke `callback(err)` when things break outside of the io event handlers. Still, the OP should have been able to infer much of this from the unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified one too many arguments; so, your callback is in the wrong position.

`Encryptor.encryptFile()` defines handling for 4-5 arguments:

```
Encryptor.encryptFile = function(inputPath, outputPath, key, options, callback) {

  if(typeof options === 'function') {
    callback = options;
    options = {};
  }

  // and so on...
```

Your code has 6:

```
encryptor.encryptFile('file.txt', 'encrypted.zaseth', message, key, options, function(err){
                                                      // ^-- what is this?
```

That `message` argument shifts everything down. `encryptFile()` thinks that your message is the key, your key is options, your options are the callback.... and ignores the callback entirely. It probably also causes errors to be thrown before the error handling due to the unexpectedly invalid argument types.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my issue as I already tried without my extra argument. So this would not work as well.

Comment: The source code clearly shows that a sixth argument is never handled, i.e. providing the callback in that position means it will never get invoked. @SunleafStudios, your extra `message` argument needs to go away, the `encryptFile()` method doesn't expect it.

Comment: @SunleafStudios Do you even look at the errors your application crashes with? Once I actually tried to run your code I quickly worked out the two separate issues your application has by simply observing the errors it throws.